# How do I log output of a shell script and also display on the screen?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, logging

I am running a script called upgrade.sh

ANd upgrade.sh calls a script called roll.sh

```
roll.sh >> logfile.text
```

But roll.sh has some questions and prompts, and the redirect is preventing those outputs from hitting the screen. I cannot edit roll.sh.

I also tried `results=$(roll.sh)

Even then, the output was not coming onto the screen

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `tee`, it was created specifically for this purpose: to forward standard input to the screen and one or more files. Make sure to use the `-a` option to append to `logfile.text` if you don't want to overwrite it.

```
roll.sh | tee -a logfile.text
```

Comment: The only thing that I would add is that you should probably do ```roll.sh 2>&1 | tee -a logfile.txt``` to also capture error output

Answer (score 1):

You want `tee`:

```
TEE(1)                           User Commands                          TEE(1)



NAME
       tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
```

Answer (score 1):

A common way to handle that is to have the script write its prompts to stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: True, but he said he can't modify `roll.sh`